# Want to have functionlity like IncrementalProjectBuilder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In android eclipse the build is generated in following steps as eclipse generate build using ant,

1. Android resource manager
2. Android pre-compiler
3. Java builder
4. Android package builder

Using [IncrementalProjectBuilder](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2012/10/integrating-custom-builder.html) class I can inject my code in the project before 2nd step.

Now I want to do the same thing in Android studio. Can any one know how I will get this point to where I can insert code before compiling the code?

> [image]

Comment: you can esily hind in help of android studio

Comment: Sorry not getting you digvesh, can you please elaborate or give me some link suggestions.

Comment: wait a minute i will give you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing i have achieved by making plugin and appling this plugin to android studio.

And for making plugin of android studio i have used [IntelliF IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) IDE.

For more [detail](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development).